# Easy way to delete a shelve .dat file left behind by my Python program?

Tags: python, shelve

So I have a python program that ends up leaving a .dat file from the `shelve` function behind after execution. I would like my program to delete or clear that file once it is done. My textbook only mentions how to create a .dat file but not how to clear it. Any good commands out there to take care of this? I don't need the .dat file again after my program runs to completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy:

```
import sys, os
sys.atexit.register( os.remove, path_to_file )
```

runs `os.remove( path_to_file )` when the Python interpreter exists in a normal (not killed/crashed) way. But you need to make sure the file is closed by then.

Answer (score 2):

Register an `atexit` handler to do the cleanup for you ([as described in the documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html)).